# Having trouble compiling an Orchard (v.1.5) project in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, orchardcms

First, I have no experience with .NET at all, I'm a front-end developer.

I agreed to help out someone with a website they own since they can't get in touch with the guy who originally set it up. It's running Orchard v1.5.1.0. I was under the impression that I could just download the entire wwwroot/ folder over FTP and open it as a webpage in Visual Studio (I'm using VS Express 2013 for Web).

Now, my problem is that while I can run the app just fine (I guess because I also got the bin/ folders with their DLLs when I fetched the whole thing over FTP) Visual Studio complains about compilation errors when I try to build it.

In one of the Modules, `Amba.ImageMultipicker`, there is a `Views/Admin/Index.cshtml` file that gets an error on the first line where it tries to do `@using Orchard.Media.Services`, and the error is `The type or namespace name "Media" does not exist in the namespace "Orchard" (are you missing an assembly reference?)`.

(I have an Orchard.Media folder under Modules, so it's there. Somewhere.)

I have tried

- Adding `<add namespace="Orchard.Media" />` to web.config
- Dropping the DLL from the bin folder in the Orchard.Media module into Dependencies
- Verified that `Amba.Imagemultipicker.csproj` has a ProjectReference to `Orchard.Media.csproj` and that the relative path is correct.

Am I missing something extremely basic here? I really don't want to go back and say I can't help out, but if I can't get the flipping thing to run locally there's no way I am going to start modifying their Themes and hope it works on the production server.

Sidenote:
I thought it was wierd that I didn't get a bin folder for the module when I downloaded the entire site, and I notice there isn't one on the live production site either. Is it possible that the whole site is running with this error?